# create multiple columns with each column as a sequence of numbers in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Problem: I wanted to add three columns in my data frame with each column being a sequence of numbers. But I want each column to vary with the other column. So here's an example data frame:

```
data <- read.table(text="
group1  group2  rate
A     D     0.01     
A     D     0.001
A     D     0.0001  
B     D     0.01    
B     D     0.001      
B     D     0.0001
D     A     0.01     
D     A     0.001
D     A     0.0001  
D     B     0.01    
D     B     0.001      
D     B     0.0001",
                   header=TRUE)
```

So first I extended my data frame to accommodate the combinations of numbers that I want for the 3 columns. I used 125 because I have 5 numbers for each sequence.

```
dataext <- data[rep(seq_len(nrow(data)), 125), ]
```

Then, I created my new column using the sequence of number that I want:

```
dataext$var1 <- rep_len (seq(0,1, 0.25), length.out=125)
dataext$var2 <- rep_len (seq(0,1, 0.25), length.out=125)
dataext$var3 <- rep_len (seq(0,1, 0.25), length.out=125)
```

An example of my desired output is:

```
group1  group2  rate    var1    var 2   var3
    A     D     0.01     0      0       0           
    A     D     0.001    0      0       0               
    A     D     0.0001   0      0       0
    A     D     0.01     0.25   0       0           
    A     D     0.001    0.25   0       0               
    A     D     0.0001   0.25   0       0
    A     D     0.01     0.25   0.25    0           
    A     D     0.001    0.25   0.25    0               
    A     D     0.0001   0.25   0.25    0
    A     D     0.01     0.25   0.25    0.25            
    A     D     0.001    0.25   0.25    0.25                
    A     D     0.0001   0.25   0.25    0.25
```

I hope this is clear enough. Any leads on how to do it right are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet to ask for clarification, but it appears that you want every combination between group1, group2, rate, var1, var2, and var3.

You can use expand.grid to achieve this.

```r
data <- read.table(text="
group1  group2  rate
                   A     D     0.01     
                   A     D     0.001
                   A     D     0.0001  
                   B     D     0.01    
                   B     D     0.001      
                   B     D     0.0001
                   D     A     0.01     
                   D     A     0.001
                   D     A     0.0001  
                   D     B     0.01    
                   D     B     0.001      
                   D     B     0.0001",
                   header=TRUE)

g1 <- levels(data$group1)
g2 <- levels(data$group2)
r <- levels(factor(data$rate))
var1 <- var2 <- var3 <- factor(seq(0,1,0.25))

dataout <- expand.grid(g1,g2,r,var1,var2,var3)

colnames(dataout) <- c("group1", "group2", "rate","var1","var2","var3")

View(dataout)
```

If you are just looking for the specific combinations you already have for group1, group2, and rate you can make a new column indicating those unique combinations and run the expand.grid

```r
data <- read.table(text="
group1  group2  rate
                   A     D     0.01     
                   A     D     0.001
                   A     D     0.0001  
                   B     D     0.01    
                   B     D     0.001      
                   B     D     0.0001
                   D     A     0.01     
                   D     A     0.001
                   D     A     0.0001  
                   D     B     0.01    
                   D     B     0.001      
                   D     B     0.0001",
                   header=TRUE)
dataext <- data[rep(seq_len(nrow(data)), 125), ]

data$key <- seq(1:length(data$group1))

dataout2 <- expand.grid(data$key,var1,var2,var3)
colnames(dataout2) <- c("key","var1","var2","var3")

datafin <- cbind(dataext,dataout2[2:4])

View(datafin)
```

Comment: I only want combinations for var1-3. I managed to do it using expand.grid too.

Answer (score 0):

So, I forgot that there is an `expand.grid` option for checking column combinations. Here's how I got the data frame that I want.

```
a <- list (var1 = (seq(0,1, 0.25)), var2 = (seq(0,1, 0.25)), var3 = (seq(0,1, 0.25)) )
c<- expand.grid(a)
expv<- c[rep(seq_len(nrow(c)), 12), ]

dataext$var1 <- expv$var1
dataext$var2 <- expv$var2
dataext$var3 <- expv$var3
```

I checked manually the resulting data frame but I also tried to plot it.

```
datamelt <- melt(dataext, id.vars = c ("group1", "group2", "rate"), value.name= "val", variable.name ="varsname" )

ggplot(datamelt, aes(x=as.factor(rate), y=val, color=varsname)) + geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge()) + facet_grid(group1~group2)
```

I think it worked. :)